# How to convert chart.js library chart to image in pure node.js without using HTML and CSS?

Tags: node.js, chart.js

Currently I need a chart to display in Microsoft Bot framework. So I used chart.js
library to generate the chart. Now I want to convert it to the .png image format.So that I can display in Bot.

So How I **convert chart.js chart to image in node.js without using HTML and CSS.**

Here is my chart code

```html
var Canvas = require('canvas')
  , canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(500, 500)
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  , Chart = require('nchart')
  , fs = require('fs');

var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'polarArea',
data:{
labels:['Strength','Skill','Health','Speed','Luck'],
datasets:[
{
label:'Points',
backgroundColor:['#f1c40f','#e67e22','#16a085','#16a085','#16a085'],
data:[10,20,55,30,10]
}
]
},
options: {
    animation:{
        animateScale : true
    }  
 }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543729/how-to-render-a-graph-as-image-in-node

Comment: This example is built on Bot Builder V3, but could easily be ported to V4: https://github.com/nwhitmont/botbuilder-vega/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of turning an nchart into a .png and base64 encoding it into an attachment:

```
const Canvas = require('canvas');
const Chart = require('nchart');

...

if (turnContext.activity.text == "chart")
{                
        let canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(500, 500);
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        new Chart(ctx).Pie(
            [
                {
                    "value": 50
                    , "color": "#E2EAE9"
                }
                , {
                    "value": 100
                    , "color": "#D4CCC5"
                }
                , {
                    "value": 40
                    , "color": "#949FB1"
                }
            ]
            , {
                scaleShowValues: true
                , scaleFontSize: 24
            }
        );

        const buf = canvas.toBuffer('image/png', { compressionLevel: 3, filters: canvas.PNG_FILTER_NONE })  
        const reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
        const base64Image = Buffer.from(buf).toString('base64');
        reply.attachments = [{
            name: 'architecture-resize.png',
            contentType: 'image/png',
            contentUrl: `data:image/png;base64,${ base64Image }`
        }];
        reply.text = 'Chart';
        turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
}
```

Bot Framework Emulator:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful response, but i had already tried this one but i cannot able to bring the legend of this pie chart. So only i dropped this nchart package. Is this possible to bring the legend of this pie chart.