# Is there a way to display labels on pie chart sections using nchart?

Tags: chart.js, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I was using the information from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021345/how-to-convert-chart-js-library-chart-to-image-in-pure-node-js-without-using-htm/) to make a pie chart for a Microsoft Teams bot, but could not figure out how to display the percentages for each section on the chart. Is there a way to do so?

I tried adding a 'label' property onto each section along with 'value' and 'color', since I saw in the [source code for nchart](https://github.com/my-archives/nchart/blob/master/examples/doughnut.json.js) that 'label' is used for doughnut charts. I tried setting 'label' to several different values, including the percentage for each section, the name for what it represented, etc. Here is what my code looked like for the pie chart data:

```
const colorArr = ["#29C5F6", "#D4CCC5", "#949FB1", "#ff0080", "#8A2BE2", "#3CB043", "#ED7014", "#FCAE1E"]

const valueArr = [50, 100, 40, 75, 25]

for (let i = 0; i < valueArr.length; i++) {
            pieChartSectionArr[i] = {
              "value": valueArr[i],
              "color": colorArr[i],
              "label": valueArr[i]
            }
          }
```

This didn't change my chart at all, and even when I tried copying the linked example, the doughnut chart did not have any labels displayed. I was hoping that there would be some text displayed on top of each section.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I see now you mentioned `nchart` in the title; the solution below is based on standard chart.js, the latest version; it works well with node using [`node-canvas`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) - a similar setting to the answer to the older question you referenced.

`nchart` is unfortunately bound to a (very) old version of `chart.js`, which is not compatible to the plugin, nor to many other new features of `chart.js`.

To run the code below with `npm`, after you create a project with `npm init`, save the code to `index.js`, then `npm install chart.js`, `npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels`, `npm install canvas`.

---

Now there's the plugin [`chartjs-plugin-datalabels`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) that works well to put labels on pie chart slices.

Here's a minimal example that works:

```js
const { Chart } = require("chart.js/auto");
const ChartDataLabels = require('chartjs-plugin-datalabels');
const { createCanvas } = require("canvas");

const fs = require("fs");

const width = 1200, height = 800;

const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
            ]
        }]
    },
    options:{
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'center',
                color: '#000',
                font: {size: '40px'},
                backgroundColor: null,
            },
        }
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
});

const buffer = canvas.toBuffer("image/png");
fs.writeFileSync("./image.png", buffer);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer! Yeah I'm honestly considering switching over to chart.js because there seems to be more documentation out there for it than for nchart.

Comment: With all due respect for nchart authors work, I strongly suggest you do that; nchart seems to have its latest update 8 years ago, and using node canvas can be very easy with a recipe like the one in the code above.